# How can I place the subfigures vertically?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am trying to place two subfigures vertically. The code I am using is:

```
\begin{figure*}[htp]
  \centering
 \includegraphics[width=15.0cm, height=4.6cm,keepaspectratio]{Figure2.png}
 \caption{Caption1}\label{fig2a}
 \includegraphics[width=15.0cm,height=4.6cm,keepaspectratio]{Figure2.png}
 \caption{caption2}\label{fig2b}
\caption{caption3}\label{fig2}
\end{figure*}
```

Which places figure like below:
[image]

But I want LaTex to treat each of the two figures as subfigures, so for example, I want to have subcaptions for each figure like 'a) model 1' and 'b) model 2'. So I don't get the captions 'Figure2' and 'Figure3' underneath each figure. How can I do this? Thank you,

Note: I need to use `figure*` instead of `figure` because my LaTeX template is 2-columned for texts. The template can be accessed at https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/instructions-for-naacl-hlt-2019-proceedings/xyyfwfkswhth

Comment: You also can load the `cuted` packahge and use the `strip` environment, which uses the single-column mode in a two-column document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try t use `subfigure` defined in the `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}  % <----

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \setkeys{Gin}{width=15.0cm, height=4.6cm,keepaspectratio}
\begin{subfigure}{15cm}  % <----
 \includegraphics{Figure2.png}
 \caption{Model 1}
 \label{fig1a}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{15cm}  % <----
 \includegraphics{Figure2.png}
 \caption{Model 2}
 \label{fig1b}
\end{subfigure}
%
\caption{Models}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: What is this `  \setkeys{Gin}{width=15.0cm, height=4.6cm,keepaspectratio}`  for ?

Comment: @EduardoReis, for determine size of group of images, which preserve their aspect ratio.